# AWS file upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, distcp, s3distcp

**I want to upload few files into AWS bucket from hadoop. I have
    AWS ACCESS KEY, SECRET KEY and S3 IMPORT PATH.**

I am not able to access though AWS CLI command.
I set the keys in aws credential file.
I tried to do “ aws s3 ls”
I am getting error as

```
An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

Since the above code didn’t work, I tried using distcp command as below.

```
hadoop distcp -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=root.mr.sbg.sla -Dfs.s3a.proxy.host=qypprdproxy02.ie.xxx.net  -Dfs.s3a.proxy.port=80  -Dfs.s3a.endpoint=s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com -Dfs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider="org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider" -Dfs.s3a.access.key="AXXXXXXXXXXQ" -Dfs.s3a.secret.key="4I9nXXXXXXXXXXXXHA" -Dfs.s3a.session.token="FQoDYXdzECkaDNBtHNfS5sKxXqNdMyKeAuqLbVXG72KvcPmUtnpLGbM7UE59zjvNNo0u8mWlslCEvZcZLxXw1agAInzGH8vnGleqxjzuBBgXMXXXXXXXG0zpHA8eyrwCZqUBXSg9cdqevv1sFT8lUIEi5uTGLjHXgkQoBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXt80Rp4vb3P7k5N2AVZmuVvM/SEH/qMLiFabDbVliGXqw7MHXTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtW8JvmOFPR3nGdQ4VKzw0deSbNmL/BCivfh9pf7ubm5RFRSLxqcdoT7XAXIWf1jJguEGygcBkFRh2Ztvr8OYcG78hLEJX61ssbKWXokOKTBMnUxx4b0jIG1isXerDaO6RRVJdBrTXn2Somzigo4ZbL0wU=" TXXXX/Data/LiXXXXL/HS/ABC/part-1517397360173-r-00000 s3a://data-import-dev/1012018.csv
```

for the above command also I getting below error.

> 18/11/09 00:55:40 INFO http.AmazonHttpClient: Configuring Proxy. Proxy
>   Host: qypprdproxy02.ie.XXXX.net Proxy Port: 80 18/11/09 00:55:40 WARN
>   s3a.S3AFileSystem: Client: Amazon S3 error 400: 400 Bad Request; Bad
>   Request (retryable)
>
> com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad
>   Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad
>   Request; Request ID: 121931CAB75C3BB0), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   jn/iTngZS83+A5U8e2gjQsyArDC68E+r0q/Sll0gkSCn0h5yDaG17TEb9HNSx7o590hmofguJIg=
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1107)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1070)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:312)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2815)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:98)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2852)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2834)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:387)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:205)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:131)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:441) 18/11/09 00:55:40
>   ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments: 
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSS3IOException: doesBucketExist on
>   segmentor-data-import-dev:
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad
>   Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad
>   Request; Request ID: 121931CAB75C3BB0), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   jn/iTngZS83+A5U8e2gjQsyArDC68E+r0q/Sll0gkSCn0h5yDaG17TEb9HNSx7o590hmofguJIg=:
>   Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad
>   Request; Request ID: 121931CAB75C3BB0)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2815)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:98)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2852)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2834)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:387)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:205)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:131)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:441) Caused by:
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad
>   Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad
>   Request; Request ID: 121931CAB75C3BB0), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   jn/iTngZS83+A5U8e2gjQsyArDC68E+r0q/Sll0gkSCn0h5yDaG17TEb9HNSx7o590hmofguJIg=
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1107)
>     at
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1070)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:312)
>     ... 11 more Invalid arguments: doesBucketExist on
>   segmentor-data-import-dev:
>   com.cloudera.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad
>   Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad
>   Request; Request ID: 121931CAB75C3BB0), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   jn/iTngZS83+A5U8e2gjQsyArDC68E+r0q/Sll0gkSCn0h5yDaG17TEb9HNSx7o590hmofguJIg=:
>   Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad
>   Request; Request ID: 121931CAB75C3BB0) usage: distcp OPTIONS
>   [source_path...] 
>                 OPTIONS  -append                       Reuse existing data in target files and
>                                  append new data to them if possible  -async                        Should distcp execution be blocking  -atomic                       Commit all changes or none  -bandwidth               Specify bandwidth per map in MB  -delete
>   Delete from target, files missing in source  -diff 
>   Use snapshot diff report to identify the
>                                  difference between source and target  -f                       List of files that need to be copied  -filelimit               (Deprecated!) Limit number of files copied
>                                  to <= n  -filters                 The path to a file containing a list of
>                                  strings for paths to be excluded from the
>                                  copy.  -i                            Ignore failures during copy  -log                     Folder on
>   DFS where distcp execution logs
>                                  are saved  -m                       Max number of concurrent maps to use for
>                                  copy  -mapredSslConf           Configuration for ssl config file, to use
>                                  with hftps://. Must be in the classpath.  -numListstatusThreads    Number of threads to use for
>   building file
>                                  listing (max 40).  -overwrite                    Choose to overwrite target files
>                                  unconditionally, even if they exist.  -p                       preserve status (rbugpcaxt)(replication,
>                                  block-size, user, group, permission,
>                                  checksum-type, ACL, XATTR, timestamps). If
>                                  -p is specified with no , then
>                                  preserves replication, block size, user,
>                                  group, permission, checksum type and
>                                  timestamps. raw.* xattrs are preserved when
>                                  both the source and destination paths are
>                                  in the /.reserved/raw hierarchy (HDFS
>                                  only). raw.* xattrpreservation is
>                                  independent of the -p flag. Refer to the
>                                  DistCp documentation for more details.  -rdiff                   Use target snapshot diff report to identify
>                                  changes made on target  -sizelimit               (Deprecated!) Limit number of files copied
>                                  to <= n bytes  -skipcrccheck                 Whether to skip CRC checks between source
>                                  and target paths.  -strategy                Copy strategy to use. Default is dividing
>                                  work based on file sizes  -tmp                     Intermediate work path to be used for
>                                  atomic commit  -update                       Update target, copying only missingfiles or
>                                  directories

Please let me know on how to achieve this.

Comment: Any help for this :(

Comment: you need to attach a role and policy for that user to talk to your s3 bucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. This issue may arise when files inside ~.aws are modified manually and not via the "aws configure" command.

Did you try to:

1. Delete the "config" and "credentials" files (located at ~.aws)
2. run the "aws configure" command (recreating the files you deleted in #1)

That has fixed the problem for me.

This is mainly because I use other tools that also modify these files.

I hope it helps.